# operator differential equation

Tags: operator-theory

let be the differential equation for the operator 'X'

$$  \frac{dX(t)}{dt} = A(t) X(t) $$

the formal solution is the exponential operator

$$ X(t)=X(0)e^{ \int_{0}^{t}A(u)} $$

of course i should expand the exponential interal into a series but it could happen that for different times the operators $ A(t) , A(t1) $ do not commute so how can i solve the operator lienar system ??

how does it cahnge if $ x(t) $ is a vector on a finite dimensional space and $ A(t) $ is a Matrix ? thanks

Comment: If you fix the order of multiplication, it doesn't matter if you have $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}X_i=\sum_k A_{ik}X_k$ or $\forall j.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}X_{ij}=\sum_k A_{ik}X_{kj}$. And if your matrix $A(t)$ is tractible for exponentiation a fixed $t$, it might help to know that solution of $ y'(t)=A(t)\ y(t)+b(t) $ is $y(t)=S(t,0)\ y_0+\int_0^t\ S(t,s)\ b(s)\ \mathrm ds$ with $S(t,0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ \mathrm{exp}\left({\frac{t}{n}A(\frac{n-1}{n}t)}\right)\cdots \ \mathrm{exp}\left({\frac{t}{n}A(0)}\right)$. (see "Partial Differential Equations: Basic Theory" by Taylor)